# innerHTML parse for Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, innerhtml

I am adding text to a textArea via Javascript in Chrome (doing it a totally different way in Firefox/IE as Chrome does not support contentWindows).

Here is my code:

```
document.getElementById("vB_Editor_001_textarea").value += '<font color="white"><b>' + numberLabel + ':</b> ' + armory + '</font><br/>';
```

This HTML is getting put directly into the textArea without being parsed.  How can I make it parse into regular text with the HTML markup when it hits the textArea?

Thanks!

Comment: @user554095 If my answer helped you solve your problem, you should accept it. If not, please clarify what further help you require.

Answer (score 1):

How about `myTextArea.innerHTML = '...';`?